# Unity not coming up after 12.10 -> 13.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.10, unity, upgrade, 13.04

I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04.

When I start Ubuntu, I get to the login screen fine and can input my password and login. However, after I log in, I'm greeted with just a blank screen that has only the default desktop wallpaper on it and nothing else. I can open up a terminal using Ctrl-Alt-T but I couldn't really figure out where to go from there to fix this problem.

I'm thinking a reinstall of some packages may cure this. Suggestions? (Thanks in advance)

Comment: I just updated ubuntu and I have the same problem, though I think this guy found the solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/306328/unity-disappeared-after-updating Check all the comments in his post

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following commands in command-line:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get purge unity
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You can get to command-line using CTRL-ALT-F3, and get back into the GUI mode by using CTRL-ALT-F7. You will need to log in using your username and password in CTRL-ALT-F7. The password display won't change when you type into it.

Probably not all of the above commands are going to help, but I suggest using all of them just to try to catch whatever is causing the error.